# IE8: Upload Files with AJAX, PHP and progressbar

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer-8, upload, progress-bar

I can't believe it. I just created a nice upload script.
It works perfectly with chrome and firefox, but ie8 doesn't support the formdata object.
I need to get it worked with IE8.
I want to use my script for chrome and firefox. If someaccess access my webapp with ie, it should automatically recognzie which browser it is and load the alternative script.

Any idea how to create a upload script with progessbar for ie?

Note: I don't want to use any fany upload plugins or other languages like flash or silverlight. Also don't link on fancy upload plugins like uploadfiy. You know, i want to unterstand what i've created here.

**EDIT**
Ok, i found a solution, but i have only one last problem. I need a progress bar.
This is my code: `http://193.109.52.60/dario/ie`
Any idea how to get this worked?

Comment: You cannot detect progress in ajax call... Its either success or error.
Although you can show upload animation in loop until success function is not called...

Comment: It is possible to track progress in IE9 and earlier, even with the iframe approach, theoretically, it seems.  I haven't investigated this yet, but there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/issues/506), scheduled for a future milestone, in my uploader project that involves use of an Apache or nginx UploadProgress module.

Comment: @Dealock Your refernce to antoher question/anwser was helpful. I "just" need now to get it worked with a progressbar. Any ideas? Note: See my updated anwser for script.

Answer (score 0):

Reinventing the wheel, especially when it comes to file uploading, is always a recipe for disaster.  There are existing libraries out there that have already solved this problem very well.  Have a look at [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com), which has many features, is open-source, does not use or depend on Java or Flash (which is a very good thing these days) and has an optional jQuery plug-in, if you are a jQuery user (if not, you can use it without the jQuery plug-in, and all features are still available).

Answer (score -1):

IE8 doesnt support html5 fully, so you will have to use another technology to make a progress bar work.

I know you dont want a link to a plugin, but you shouldnt reinvent the wheel again, so
take a look at plupload @ http://www.plupload.com/ !

Its open-source and if you really want to know how progress bars are done, digg into the code.

Lucian